# Find window by Storyboard ID

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow

I'm trying to get a window by it's ID, so I can close it, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Specifically, I'm looking for something like the following, however this doesn't seem to work.

```
- (void) closeWindowByName:(NSString *)windowName
{

    NSWindow *activeWindow;

    NSStoryboard *storyBoard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    activeWindow = [storyBoard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:windowName];
    [activeWindow close];
}
```

Why doesn't this work, and how can I fix it?

Comment: @alex-k What was wrong with how I phrased my question before?

Comment: Hey :) You didn't actually phrase your question before! That was the issue - you didn't actually say what you wanted. You ended your post with an apology, and then a thank you, which I removed because they are excess noise that Stack Overflow tends to prefer that you leave out.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for your hard work, then!

Comment: As one might gather from the name, the documentation for `instantiateControllerWithIdentifier` mentions that it creates and returns a new controller instance.   So you create `activeWindow` and tell it to close without ever showing it.

Comment: @stevesliva I had a sneaking suspicion initializing a new window wasn't what I wanted to do. Thanks for the comment! Is it possible to find a window by it's identifier?

Comment: No idea, which is why I didn't answer.  Getting to the window depends on where the code is, I suppose.  You can get a list of windows from the app, or you can get to it through the view hierarchy, I think.  But unless Apple updated NSWindowController with an identifier property and didn't tell anyone, it's pretty difficult to do it how you want from what I gathered by poking around.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help! I guess I'll look into other ways of getting a reference to a window.